# React Native Swipeable animation does not work

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

I am having this weird behavior with react-native-gesture-handler's Swipeable component. Intro animations don't work but after pressing the button in Swipeable component, animations work fading out. Here is my `BookmarkItem` component with `Swipeable` component:

```
  renderLeftActions = (progress, dragX) => {
    const trans = dragX.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 50, 100, 101],
      outputRange: [-20, 0, 0, 1],
      
    });

    const localStyles = {
      rectButton: {
        alignItems: "stretch",
        justifyContent: "center",
      },
      icon: {
        transform: [{ translateX: trans }],
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        height: '100%',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)'
      },
    };

    return (
      <RectButton
        style={localStyles.rectButton}
        onPress={() => {
          this.props.removeFromBookmarks(this.props.title, this.props.p);
          this.swipableRef?.current?.close();
        }}
      >
        <Animated.View style={localStyles.icon}>
          <Icon name="heart" size={35} color="rgb(245, 66, 66)" />
        </Animated.View>
      </RectButton>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Swipeable
        ref={this.swipableRef}
        renderLeftActions={this.renderLeftActions}
        overshootLeft={false}
      >
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPress}>
          <Text numberOfLines={2} style={styles.sectionText}>
            {this.props.p}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Swipeable>
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Could you try the example code in the docs and see if that is working for you?  It's all at the bottom of the page. https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/api/components/swipeable/

Comment: What does ‘onPress’ in your render? Maybe something that could conflict with the animation? It would be helpful to add as much as possible of the component in your example.

Comment: I would also suggest to delete everything except the bare minimum for this animation to work. Remove all the evens and styles and see if it still does the same thing

Comment: I did remove everything except the bare minimum. Problem persists. onPress is just a callback function that calls a method from props. The problem started happening after I upgraded to react-native-gesture-handler@2.3.0. It was working before. Tried wrapping the entire app with `GestureHandlerRootView` but it didn't help either.

Comment: What version did you have before? I could help look through the changelog of the updates

Comment: I tried on a fresh project and it worked fine for me with the example code from the docs. I would try to remove <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPress}> in the render. And maybe double check if the correct version is linked